# Condensing multiple methods into one

Tags: c#, methods

I have this method that I have essentially duplicated and hardcoded three times, but I would like to condense the three into one method and dynamically change the Input.GetKey(). I am just unsure of how to do that.

The main method is:

```cs
private void AugmentAbility1(AugmentData augmentData)
{
    switch (augmentData.state)
    {
        case AbilityState.ready:
            if (Input.GetKey(ability1Key))
            {
                augmentIndex = augmentData.index;
                augmentList[augmentIndex].augmentSkill.Ability();
                augmentData.state = AbilityState.active;
                augmentData.activeTime = augmentList[augmentIndex].augmentSkill.activeTime;
            }

            break;
        case AbilityState.active:
            if (augmentData.activeTime > 0)
            {
                augmentData.activeTime -= Time.deltaTime;
            }
            else
            {
                augmentData.state = AbilityState.cooldown;

                augmentData.cooldownTime = augmentList[augmentIndex].augmentSkill.cooldownTime;
            }
            break;
        case AbilityState.cooldown:
            if (augmentData.cooldownTime > 0)
            {
                augmentData.cooldownTime -= Time.deltaTime;
                Debug.Log("TimeLeft: " +augmentData.cooldownTime);
            }
            else
            {
                augmentData.state = AbilityState.ready;
                Debug.Log("state changed to: " + augmentData.state);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

In addition to AugmentAbility1, I have 2 other methods(AugmentAbility2,AugmentAbility3) where I pass in augmentData2 and augmentData3. I know I could easily use a foreach to pass those parameters in. The issue is that each AugmentAbility method has a different ability key.

`if (Input.GetKey(abilityXKey))`

The separate variables being:

```cs
ability1Key = Keycode.Alpha1
ability2Key = Keycode.Alpha2
ability3Key = Keycode.Alpha3
```

The three methods are currently sitting in my Update() like so, in order to catch the different key inputs.

```cs
Update()
{
    AugmentAbility1(augmentData1);
    AugmentAbility2(augmentData2);
    AugmentAbility3(augmentData3);
}
```

Comment: So why not pass abilityKey as an argument?

Comment: Please show the full code for each method, along with the full code for each type and enum used. I'd like to be able to copy and compile your code. Then it can be refactored.

Comment: @Faultde, i actually recommend you extract each case into their own dedicated method. There is a code smell called Long Method you should look into. Its better to have a more methods that provide a specific outcome, vs a single big method. After that extraction i recommend then think about refactoring to identify common logic.

Comment: Please provide the full code as requested previously.

Answer (score 1):

Say hello to C# syntactic sugar in the form of Action and Func

In this case:

```
private void AugmentAbility(AugmentData augmentData, 
KeyCode expectedKeyCode, 
Action<AugmentData> completionWhenMatchedKey)
{
switch (augmentData.state)
    {
        case AbilityState.ready:
            if (Input.GetKey(expectedKeyCode))
            {
               completionWhenMatchedKey(augmentData);
            }

            break;
        case AbilityState.active:
            if (augmentData.activeTime > 0)
            {
                augmentData.activeTime -= Time.deltaTime;
            }
            else
            {
                augmentData.state = AbilityState.cooldown;

                augmentData.cooldownTime = 
                       augmentList[augmentIndex].augmentSkill.cooldownTime;
            }
            break;
        case AbilityState.cooldown:
            if (augmentData.cooldownTime > 0)
            {
                augmentData.cooldownTime -= Time.deltaTime;
                Debug.Log("TimeLeft: " +augmentData.cooldownTime);
            }
            else
            {
                augmentData.state = AbilityState.ready;
                Debug.Log("state changed to: " + augmentData.state);
            }
            break;
    }
}
// Now to call it:

public void Update() {
    AugmentAbility(augmentData1, KeyCode.Alpha1, (augmentData) => {
                augmentIndex = augmentData.index;
                augmentList[augmentIndex].augmentSkill.Ability();
                augmentData.state = AbilityState.active;
                augmentData.activeTime = augmentList[augmentIndex].augmentSkill.activeTime;
    });
    AugmentAbility(augmentData2, KeyCode.Alpha2, (augmentData) => {
        // Do sth else
    });
    AugmentAbility(augmentData3, KeyCode.Alpha3, (augmentData) => {
        // Do sth entirely different
    });
}
```